# Putting Divs Next to each other using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried using the `row` class but it was not solving the problem. I am just trying to take two divs and put them next to each other using only bootstrap and not css. (It's a corner case where I can't add any css) Is there a way to do this?

Basically I have this:

```
<div class="OuterMostClass row">
    <div class="outerClass">
        <button class="btn">button1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="outerClass2">
        <button class="btn">button2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want the two buttons to be next to each other and due to limitations I can't add any css other than bootstrap. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code sample doesn't show a parent div with the `container` or `container-fluid` class and your columns are missing size classes.

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="OuterMostClass row">
        <div class="outerClass col-xs-6">
            <button class="btn">button1</button>
        </div>
        <div class="outerClass2 col-xs-6">
            <button class="btn">button2</button>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to add the `pull-left` class to the buttons but as Matthew points out adding a container makes it easier to take care of other spacing